# Difference between developing for smartphone / tablet?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Is there a difference between developing for a smartphone vs for a tablet? i.e. iPhone vs iPad, Android vs Android Tablet. What are the main differences to take into account? I know its a broad question, but trying to wrap my head around the difference.

Edit:
If a company can develop for iPhone apps, does that mean that the company could easily develop for iPad as well? Do companies specialize in iOS smartphones and not iOS tablets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best answers is from what you'll find on developer.android.com

> Each screen size offers different possibilities and challenges for
>   user interaction, so in order to truly satisfy and impress your users,
>   your application must go beyond merely supporting multiple screens: it
>   must optimize the user experience for each screen configuration.

Usually the programming is the same the only change is layout and maybe a few extra buttons or less buttons.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is screen size. Sounds like an open door, but if you actually write apps targetted at both phones and tablets, the differences become very clear.

Take sending an email from your app. On iPhone you get a nice full-screen mailer. On iPad, full screen would be too much of it, so you need to embed it in a smaller overlay.

Take scanning a QR code. On iPhone your screen is just the right size for such a thing. An iPad is just a little too big.

Take having a "More..." menu. On iPhone, having 4 rows saying "About", "Settings", etc is a good design. Having the same 4 rows full screen on iPad looks really, really bad.

For iPhone/iPad in the examples above, you can read Android Phone vs Android Tablet of course.

On the low level OS side, there is no real difference. It's the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

UI design is the main difference. Tablets have more screen space. In most form/control-based apps (as opposed to games), this makes you redraw pretty much the whole app layout for tablets.